# Statistical models for simultaneous study designs

Tags: model, epidemiology, research-design

I have thinking about a problem that can be encountered in environmental epidemiology, but I guess in other research fields too.

**Background:** In environmental epidemiology the interest is mostly to assess the associations between an exposure (e.g. air pollution) and an health outcome (e.g. mortality).
In general, we have two types of exposure: 1) short-term exposure, defined as daily exposure values and 2) long-term exposure, mostly measured as yearly exposure values. The effect of these two types of exposure on the health outcome is usually assessed separately due to different study designs. First, usually 1) short-term exposure is associated with the outcome using the case-crossover design while for 2) long-term exposure we typically use survival designs (usually Cox PH model).

**My question is:** What if I was interested in looking at both (short- and long-term) associations at the same time while controlling for the each other? I was thinking maybe there is a way to use Joint Models for survival and binary outcomes that works in this kind of situation. I know Joint Models are used for different reasons but I am wondering..

I am  even just looking for intuitions (based on existing statistical methods) especially beyond the field of epidemiology. Maybe in econometrics or other fields someone has developed already some models that work in these situations and I have no clue.

Any ideas or directions would be highly appreciated!